# Any way in Expression Engine to simulate Wordpress' shortcode functionality?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm relatively new to Expression Engine, and as I'm learning it I am seeing some stuff missing that WordPress has had for a while. A big one for me is shortcodes, since I will use these to allow CMS users to place more complex content in place with their other content.

I'm not seeing any real equivalent to this in EE, apart from a forthcoming plugin that's in private beta.

As an initial test I'm attempting to fake shortcodes by using delimited strings (e.g. #foo#) in the content field, then using a regex to pull those out and pass them to a function that can retrieve the content out of EE's database.

This brings me to a second question, which is that in looking at EE's API docs, there doesn't appear to be a simple means of retrieving the channel entries programmatically (thinking of something akin to WP's built-in get_posts function).

So my questions are:

a) Can this be done? 
b) If so, is my method of approaching it reasonable? Or is there something stupidly obvious I'm missing in my approach?

To reiterate, my main objective here is to have some means of allowing people managing content to drop a code in place in their content that will be replaced with channel content.

Thanks for any advice or help you can give me.

Comment: i totally understand if you want to replace some #foo# tags with images or data from another field (see other answers: nsm-transplant, low_replace). But, giving editor access to shortcodes is like writing a template-engine to generate ee-template code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example of the functionality you're looking for.

1) Start by installing [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace).

2) Create two Global Variables called gv_hello and gv_goodbye with the values "Hello" and "Goodbye" respectively.

3) Put this text into the body of an entry:

[say_hello]

Nice to see you.

[say_goodbye]

4) Put this into your template, wrapping the Low Replace tag around your body field.

{exp:low_replace 
  find="[say_hello]|[say_goodbye]" 
  replace="{gv_hello}|{gv_goodbye}"
  multiple="yes"
}
    {body}
{/exp:low_replace}

5) It should output this into your browser:

> Hello
>
> Nice to see you.
>
> Goodbye

Obviously, this is a really simple example. You can put full blown HTML into your global variable. For example, we've used that to render a complex, interactive graphic that isn't editable but can be easily dropped into a page by any editor.

Unfortunately, due to parse order issues, EE tags won't work inside Global Variables. If you need EE tags in your short code output, you'll need to use [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) addon instead of Global Variables.

Answer (score 1):

Continued from the comment:

Do you have examples of the kind of shortcodes you want to support/include? Because i have doubts if controlling the page-layout from a text-field or wysiwyg-field is the way to go.

If you want editors to be able to adjust layout or show/hide extra parts on the page, giving them access to some extra fields in the channel, is (imo) much more manageable and future-proof. For instance some selectfields, a relationship (or playa) field, or a matrix, to let them choose which parts to include/exclude on a page, or which entry from another channel to pull content from.

As said in the comment: i totally understand if you want to replace some #foo# tags with images or data from another field (see other answers: nsm-transplant, low_replace). But, giving an editor access to shortcodes and picking them out, is like writing a template-engine to generate ee-template code for the ee-template-engine.

Using some custom fields to let editors pick and choose parts to embed is, i think, much more manageable.

That being said, you could make a plugin to parse the shortcodes from a textareas content, and then program a lot, to fetch data from other modules you want to support. For channel entries you could build out of the channel data library by objectiveHTML. https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data

Answer (score 0):

I hear you, I too miss shortcodes from WP -- though the reason they work so easily there is the ubiquity of `the_content()`. With the great flexibility of EE comes fewer blanket solutions.

I'd suggest looking at [NSM Transplant](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-transplant). It should fit the bill for you.

Comment: Thanks - it's an interesting video there for the advanced example. However, in the example they show they're using NSM Transplant to grab data from a channel field that's part of the entry they're displaying. Does NSM Transplant support grabbing any arbitrary content? It's unclear to me from the docs if this is the case.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. It wouldn't work with grabbing from another Channel Entries loop (since you can't safely nest Channel Entries loops within Channel Entries loops), and an embed won't work either (since embeds are parsed *after* all other tags).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a plugin called Shortcode, which you can find here at
[Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortcode)
A quote from the page:

> Shortcode aims to allow for more dynamic use of content by authors and
>   editors, allowing for injection of reusable bits of content or even
>   whole pieces of functionality into any field in EE